# Getting a "ld: cannot find -lcunit" error with CUnit

Tags: netbeans, windows-7, cygwin, ld, cunit

I'm using NetBeans 7.1 on Windows 7. I downloaded the CUnit archive and used shell scripts supplied with the archive to install it (`$make install`, etc.). I'm using Cygwin as my compiler, and whenever I try to build the unit test, I get the following error:

`/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.3.4/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lcunit`

Obviously, the linker (ld) doesn't know where to look for something, but I don't know the intricacies of how this stuff works. Searching for `lcunit` on my computer didn't return anything except for the makefile of this project.

One thing I think I should mention is that when I installed CUnit, NetBeans did not know where to look for it. It got installed into /usr/local/ and this was not one of the paths NetBeans parsed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"-lcunit" is just a flag/option instructing your compiler to link all cunit stuff in your app.
usage could be something like this (gcc):

```
gcc test.c -lcunit -o test
```

looks like your compiler doesn't know what to do with this flag... :/

Comment: Yeah, you're pretty much right. I didn't have CUnit installed for Cygwin. So yeah, my compiler didn't know about the flag.